# Core 2 EF - Redirect to Detail Page after Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, redirect, asp.net-core

I want to redirect back to the details page after an Edit. By default, after scaffolding, the code looks something like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, RecordClass recordClass)
{
    //Update Code
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

However, since I already have the ID, I want to redirect straight to the record detail page. I tried most of the RedirectToActions:

[image]

But I would either get an error, an empty Details page, or it would redirect back to Edit page with parameter. None redirected to Details with paramater.

I also tried RedirectToPage and RedirectToRoute, but none work for this purpose.

Now, I got this to work with the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, RecordClass recordClass)
{
    //Update Code
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Details) + "/" + students.IdStudent.ToString());
}
```

Altought it works, it looks horrible and I'm not sure this is the correct way of doing it.

Suggestions?

Comment: in case someone comes across this and you are wondering why the answer is not working? Dont convert the id to string ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `id` parameter like this;

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Details), new { id = students.IdStudent.ToString() });
```

Comment: I remember trying something like this and not working, probably was missing something in the syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this worked for me;

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Details), new { id = artist.Id.ToString() });
```